# Basic .click function i can't get to work jQuery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?  why this basic click function isn't getting executed to the point of sending off the alert.  I have jQuery-1.7.1.js linked to my page.

jQuery

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../fruith/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkedDark () {

$('#activate_post_checkbox').click(function(){
    alert('duh')

  $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});


}
</script>

</head>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="work">blah blah blah</div>


<input type="checkbox" id="activate_post_checkbox" value="active"  /><span id="activate_post_checkbox_text">Make my posting active immediately.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign the click event in the `document.ready` function, or call your `checkedDark()` function first.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 

  $('#activate_post_checkbox').click(function(){
      alert('duh');
      $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For one you're defining the listener in a function. Maybe that should be on document ready...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#activate_post_checkbox').click(function(){
    alert('duh')

  $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});


});
```

also, you might want to consider using .on instead of .click as this is more of a standard in later jquery versions...

```
$('#activate_post_checkbox').on('click', function(){
    alert('duh')

  $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkedDark () {

$('#activate_post_checkbox').click(function(){
    alert('duh')

  $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});


}
checkedDark ();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('#activate_post_checkbox').click(function(){
        alert('duh')

      $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the DOM is not ready at the time you're binding to the click event.
Move the script to the end of document or wrap it by `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`click` event handler will only be attached when `checkedDark` method is executed. I don't see this method getting called in your page.

Execute it on page load it will attach the handler. Try this.

```
$(function(){

   $('#activate_post_checkbox').click(function(){
       alert('duh');//Though its not the issue but add the semicolon
       $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');
    });

});
```

Or do this.

```
$(checkedDark);
```

Or call the function at the end of the page before closing body tag so that element will be available to jQuery.

```
checkedDark();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call `checkedDark ()` and put the click event inside it or make click event outside `checkedDark`  function

```
function checkedDark () {

}

$('#activate_post_checkbox').click(function(){
    alert('duh')

  $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the checkedDark function, and no handler is being attached to the checkbox. Also, you need to be sure the element is ready on the page. Use the .on() method instead of click().

```
(function checkedDark () {

$('#activate_post_checkbox').on('click', function(){
    alert('duh');

  $('#work').css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});

}());
```